# Unable to call a button click function within a webview in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webview

I am trying to call webview button click function on my own button click function but nothing seems to work.
My code is similar to this

```
buttonClick = () => {
  
this.webview.injectJavaScript(`document.getElementById('webBtn').click()`);
}

redner(){

return(
<View>

 <WebView
            source={{uri: 'https://mywebsite.com'}}

          />

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.buttonClick()}><Text> Click here </Text></TouchableOpacity>
</View>
)

}
```

I have tried the same Method with **javascript** It works **Perfect** there but I don't why its creating issues with the **WebView** in **react Native** . Any help would be Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The ref of the `WebView` was not specified.

```
<WebView      
    ref={(ref)=>{this.webview=ref;}}
    source={{uri: 'https://mywebsite.com'}}    
/>
```